# Proof that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is quasi-concave iff $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2:f(x)\geq r\}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am having some difficulty proving the theorem above.

I think I have a clue of how to prove that $A$ being convex implies that $f$ is quasi-concave.

Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1,x_2 \in A$ and $x_3$ such that $x_3=\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2$ with $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1.$

If $A$ is convex, then $x_3 \in A$, which implies that $f(x_3)\geq r$.

And I know that $f(x_1) \geq r$ and $f(x_2) \geq r$, so $\min\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\} \geq r$.

I think I need to use the definition of quasi-concave function now:
$$
f(x_3) \geq \min\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\}
$$

But I don't know how to prove this relation using what I have so far.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's recall that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is quasiconcave if for all $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then $f(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2) \geq \min \{f(x_1),f(x_2)\}$.

Let's suppose that for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $A_r := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: f(x) \geq r \}$ is convex.

Take $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Without loss of generality suppose $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$. Then, it is clear that $x_1,x_2 \in A_{f(x_2)}$. Being this set convex, we further have that $\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2 \in A_{f(x_2)}$, which means
$$
f(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2) \geq f(x_2) = \min\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\}.
$$
Hence, $f$ is quasiconcave.

EDIT:

For the converse, suppose $f$ is quasiconcave. Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and take $x_1,x_2 \in A_r$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. $x_1,x_2$ being in $A_r$ means $f(x_1) \geq r$ and $f(x_2) \geq r$, hence $\min\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\} \geq r$. Furthermore, the quasiconvexity of $f$ implies
$$
f(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2) \geq \min\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\} \geq r.
$$
That is, $\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2 \in A_r$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you how to prove the opposite implication too?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Give me a minute

Comment: Ready. If you are satisfied, please consider accepting my answer as the solution.